# Getting rid of the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" message when an image fails to load?

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

If an image doesn't exist, or somehow an image just doesn't load, is there a way to make it so this message doesn't show up in the web inspector?

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

I have tried these:

```
<img src="/path.png" onerror="this.src = '/missing.png'; this.onerror = ''; return true;"/>
<img src="/path.png" onerror="this.src = '/missing.png'; this.onerror = ''; return false;"/>
```

And I've tried it in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("img").error(function(event) {
    $(this).attr("src", "/missing.png");
    return false;
  }
});
```

That message gets output in red before any of these event handlers get access to it, is there not a way to prevent this message from showing up?

Ideally, I would be able to do this:

```
$("img").live("error", function() { $(this).attr("src", "/missing.png"); });
```

so I don't have to:

1. Write inline javascript like `<img onerror='x'/>`
2. and it would work on dynamically loaded images.

Comment: it's telling me there's an error that I don't consider an error.  it makes the app look broken.

Comment: Well, it *is an error*. Also: users don't check their Web Inspector. Can't you, as the developer, simply ignore the error?

Comment: @viatropos: Whether you consider it an error or not is not relevant. It is an error; fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you would need to check for the existence of the image prior to adding the `<img>` to the DOM. This check would have to occur server-side as far as I know; even attempting to do this with JQuery/AJAX will still result in a 404 or 403 error appearing in the console.